# Transparent JTextField on a transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, transparent

Not sure if this has been discussed before. But I am having a odd issue with transparent JTextFields added on a transparent JPanel. For some reason (I could not dig enough to find why) there are additional paintings that get carried out. Perhaps there are dirty regions that needs to be dealt with? not sure.

Let me present this simple example:

```
public class TextFieldGame extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame someFrame = new JFrame("Is this odd?");
                someFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                someFrame.setSize(200,600);

                someFrame.add(new TextFieldGame());

                someFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    public TextFieldGame() {
        setupContentPane();
    }

    private void setupContentPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final CanvasPanel canvasPanel = new CanvasPanel();
        add(canvasPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new ControlPanel(canvasPanel), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

        private final CanvasPanel canvasPanel;

        ControlPanel(CanvasPanel canvasPanel) {
            this.canvasPanel = canvasPanel;
            setupContentPane();
        }

        private void setupContentPane() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

            final JButton load = new JButton("load");
            add(load);

            load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    canvasPanel.addChildComponent(getComponent());

                    canvasPanel.revalidate();
                    canvasPanel.repaint();
                }
            });

        }

        private JComponent getComponent() {


            final JPanel container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            container.setOpaque(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                final JTextField textField = new JTextField("why you no work?") {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                        return new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, getPreferredSize().height);
                    }
                };

                textField.setOpaque(false);

                container.add(textField);

            }
            return container;
        }
    }

    public static class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {
        private int paintCount = 0;

        CanvasPanel() {
            setupContentPane();
        }

        public void setupContentPane() {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            setBackground(Color.white);
        }

        public void addChildComponent(JComponent component) {
            component.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
            add(component);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("paint count: " + ++paintCount);
        }



    }

}
```

I have added the System out statement to show the count of paint task.

When first loaded, there will be 2/3 paints - fair enough. Then if you are to press the "Load" button, 10 transparent JTextFields will be added to a transparent JPanel, and this transparent JPanel will be added to the CanvasPanel. (Canvas panel is in turn a subchild of the JFrame). You will notice upon doing this, 11 additional paint jobs will be done.

But in theory (well in my understanding) after "Load" is pressed, only one paint job should be carried out. That is because, I have added only one child to CanvasPanel (the child itself might have 10 textfields, but they should all be painted in one shot).

Just to test my understanding, if you are to use 10 JLabels instead of the 10 JTextFields, only one paint job is carried out after "Load" is pressed. Which is what it should be.

Also, if you are to keep JTextField opaque, only one paint job is carried out. (Just tested that if instead of JTextField, a JTextArea is used, one paint is done)

What is going on? Note that JLabel is transparent by default, so I am not sure why transparency of JTextField component causing these additional paints.

Please help/

Comment: Why do you think you care how many paints there are? As a general rule, you have no control over that number. Just guessing, but maybe transparent components result in more painting because the component behind them must be painted as well?

Comment: Why are you counting the number of times the component is painted? This is unnecessary. A JTextField needs to support a blinking caret. Maybe this is the difference. As long as the painting is correct, this is nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: There some other painting task I need to carry out and they are carried out every time the containing panel is refreshed. So these additional painting is effectively causing performance issue. Note that this is a simple mock example of a bigger application I am dealing with.

Perhaps the use of JTextfield to do what I am doing isn't proper. I probably should use JLabel, after all, I am actually setting editing to false to all the text field (not in the mock though) (BTW, blinking cursor doesn't show on non-editable textfield but it still paints it additional times)

Comment: Well, like we said, you don't really have any control over the painting. In fact, you might get wildly different numbers on a different computer, OS, JRE version, or even different times on the same computer depending on what else is going on. If a difference of 10 calls to paint code is causing a performance issue, you've got bigger problems to worry about.